# Adding Files to Xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode

Trying to add file to the project!

Right click on the subfolder and selected add file to projectName. I added file which are required into my project[Destination unChecked and selected folders Create groups for any added folders and selected Add to Targerts projectNameTest], and close the xcode and reopen! the file which are added to the project is not appear's.  Then again right clicked on the project selected add file's from 'workspace' and add to project [repeated same scenario]  And close the xcode still files are disappearing from my workspace.

each time i need to add the file again and again from the work space. When I close the Xcode.
 what i need to do for this issue so When i Open Xcode the files need to be appears into my workspace

Comment: Just drag and drop the file into the sidebar where your other source code is located. Simple.

Comment: already the files are there in the same folder.  but its not appears  in X-code.

Comment: May be permission issue? Do you have permissions to write to the project files?

Comment: Yes I do have the permission!

Answer (score 7):

What i do generally when I need to add extra source files to my project is :

*1. Drag the file from source to my project.*

[image]

*2. I add Tick mark to the "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" option.*

[image]

*3. Now i can seed added file into my project.*

[image]

Hope!! this helps.

Comment: I do this as well. It seems to be the most efficient, and quickest way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add files with a CLI, as I do, since I use a remote mac for development, you can check [XCodeControl](https://github.com/ikrabbe/XCodeControl) at github. This method is much faster than licking somewhere, at least if you hung over ;)