# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - React Native

Tags: react-native

I was add Facebook integration in app.xcodeproj. that was successfully working. After i was added pod install for google login. when i was open workspace and built project this error occur:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
    Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And also does not run project in react native.

use this link but not helping me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545880/apple-mach-o-linker-ditto-error-xcode-8/41072513#41072513)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted a folder of a test project in **Project Navigator** and **Targets**. It solved my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545880/apple-mach-o-linker-ditto-error-xcode-8