# Can't run React Native iOS app after uninstall a package

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I got this erro in XCODE:

[image]

It happens after I uninstall `react-native-maps`

How can I fix this error ?

Been searching, still can't solve it

Comment: you need to unlink RN-maps dependency for ios, either use command "react-native unlink react-native-maps" or you can do this manually as steps provided by @demtemm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is because you need to update your binaries in Xcode. Open your project in Xcode and check these and you should be fine:

- Go to the Libraries folder and remove AIRMaps.xcodeproj if it is in there
- Go to your project Target, under the Build Phases tab. Then go to Link Binary With Libraries and remove libAIRMaps.a from that list

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a trivial question but have you tried this?

1. Quit Xcode
2. Restart the System
3. Open Xcode Preferences.  This
   will open a pop-up window. Select 'Locations'. In Locations, you
   will see 'Derived Data'. Click on the arrow icon right next to the
   path. This will open a folder containing 'Derived Data', delete it.
4. Clean the Product and Run

From [Apple Mach-O Linker & Ditto Error - Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545880/apple-mach-o-linker-ditto-error-xcode-8)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

1. delete node_modules and package.lock.json
2. in your `ios` folder, delete `podfile.lock`
3. Then on your project root terminal run
4. `npm i`
5. `cd ios`
6. `pod update`
7. `cd ..`

Then proceed to run your app.
I think after uninstalling the package, it is still registered in your podfile so deleting and updating will just re-link your current packages